# Set com.google.android.material.chip.Chip selected color

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-chips

How do I set the selected com.google.android.material.chip.Chip color? I don't want it to be the default gray. This is a single selection chip group.

[image]

Original documentation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w9W2.png)

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipgroup"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:checkedChip="@+id/chip_program"
    app:chipSpacingHorizontal="32dp"
    app:chipSpacingVertical="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailText"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_program"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Program"
        app:chipEndPadding="16dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="16dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_normal"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/program_normal"
        app:chipEndPadding="16dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="16dp" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just set an attribute `app:chipBackgroundColor` and pass a color state list to it:

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"
    app:chipText="Test" />
```

`bg_chip_state_list` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorSecondaryLight" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>
```

However I also had to set `android:clickable` to `true` to make this work

Comment: It's working, how did you figure this out? Is this the doc? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Comment: Better mention the file location is res/color/bg_chip_state_list.xml

Comment: I don't need set clickable to true though.

Comment: Now almost the same question, how to do the same with text color?

Comment: @JeffreyLiu The docs don't mention all available attributes, so I discovered it in the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/res/values/attrs.xml)

Comment: @JeffreyLiu Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @airowe well, with the source code provided now, yes.

Comment: I had to use `state_selected` instead of `state_checked` to make it to work. I'm using `Choice Chip` style though.

Comment: and what about **checkedIconVisible** checked icon is still black how to change that too?

Comment: https://medium.com/@werder630/material-filter-and-choice-chips-d929312148d8

Comment: No need to add `clickable` and `focusable` if you use a style inheriting from one of the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip...`

Answer (score 49):

Using a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource) is a proper way. 
The only thing I want to add is using custom defined style much more clear to read especially if you want to customise a bunch of properties.

Among other things, one common style applied to all views allows you to make changes in **one** place that apply immediately to **all** views

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomChipChoice" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/background_color_chip_state_list</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_chip_state_list</item>
</style>
```

text_color_chip_state_list.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/color_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/color_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

background_color_chip_state_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color1" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/color2" />
</selector>
```

After that all you need is apply your custom style for all the Chip views like this.

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/CustomChipChoice"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="Chip text" />
```

Comment: how about set up programatically the style? I'm not able to set it properly

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting...

I have an answer, but not sure if this is the best way of applying the style programatically to views.

**1. values/attrs.xml**
`<resources>
    <attr name="CustomChipChoiceStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>`

**2. styles.xml**
    `<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        ...
        <item name="CustomChipChoiceStyle">@style/CustomChipChoice</item>
</style>`
**3. in code**
`val chip = Chip(requireContext(), null, R.attr.CustomChipChoiceStyle)`

Comment: and what about **checkedIconVisible** checked icon is still black how to change that too?

Comment: app:checkedIconVisible="true"
app:checkedIcon="@drawable/your_custom_icon"

Answer (score 18):

To change the colors in the [**`Chip`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md) you can use a custom style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/My_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
         ../>
```

With this style:

```
 <style name="My_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <!-- Chip background color selector -->
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/my_choice_chip_background_color</item>
    <!-- Border color -->
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>

    <!-- Chip text color selector -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_choice_chip_text_color</item>
    <!-- Chip close icon color selector -->
    <item name="closeIconTint">@color/mtrl_chip_close_icon_tint</item>
  </style>
```

For the **`chipBackgroundColor`** you can use a selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- 24% opacity -->
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="@color/custom" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="@color/secondaryDarkColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <!-- 12% of 87% opacity -->
  <item android:alpha="0.10" android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</selector>
```

For the **text color** you can use something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <!-- 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <!-- 38% of 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.33" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>

</selector>
```

Result for normal/selected state:

[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

For those using `alpha-05`, I found that `state_checked` was being ignored on the filterable (`parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"`) Chips. Instead, you need `state_selected`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/apricot" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/apricotSubtle"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: and what about **checkedIconVisible** checked icon is still black how to change that too?

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, you need to set the background color property of the chip element to a ColorStateList that you define. But I just wanted to point out an important note on how to do that since I ran into issues getting the different states to work.

When defining your own ColorStateList (xml resource) you need to make sure you set the different state options in the ColorStateList **BEFORE** the default color! This was tripping me up for a few days before I figured it out, so I hope this helps someone else as well.

Also, your chip needs to be clickable and focusable (checkable didn't work for me) so set these properties to true as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="@color/chipColorLight" />
    <item android:color="@color/chipColorDefault"/>
</selector>
```

If you want to programmatically set different ColorStateOptions you can do that like so:

```
binding.myChip.chipBackgroundColor = resources.getColorStateList(R.color.chip_color_state_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow changing `android:textColor` in `styles` doesn't work for me. I have to change the chip's text color programmatically (as I also create chips programmatically).

```
val chip = Chip(context)
// Apply custom MyChipChoice style to the chip
val drawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(context!!, null, 0, R.style.MyChipChoice)
chip.setChipDrawable(drawable)
// Apply text color to the chip
val colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context!!, R.color.my_choice_chip_text_color)
chip.setTextColor(colorStateList)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the Chip items in code use a state list like mentioned above and the following methods (in Java of course):

```
chip.setClickable(true);
chip.setCheckable(true);
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getColorStateList(R.color.chip_background_color));
chip.setCheckedIconVisible(false);
```

**Note:** getColorStateList requires minSdkVersion to be 23 in the build.gradle script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this...

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroupFilter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chipAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"
                app:checkedIconEnabled="false"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteBlackSwitchColor"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_all"
                app:chipIconTint="#4D4F55"
                app:chipIconVisible="true" />
     </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the `setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList cl)` method to set the color of your chip and then you can add an `setOnClickListener(new ...)` to toggle with selection and non-selection like the following code:

```
yourchip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((Chip)v).getChipBackgroundColor().equals(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,null))) {
            ((Chip)v).setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimary, null));
        } else {
            ((Chip) v).setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, null));
        }
    }
});
```

where i have used `colorPrimaryDark` for selection and `colorPrimary` for non-selection.