# Is there a way to stay on the same Chip when I press it?

Tags: android, android-chips

[image]

Hello

I am using a `Chips` in `ChipGroup` and `Chips` style theme is `Choice`

If `Choice Chip` is clicked, Chip state is change. (`background color`, etc..)

And you click it again, it will return to its original state.

What I want is that the checked state does not change when I click the same chip.

But i check another `Chip` in the checked state, the state of the previous chip must return to its

original state.

Are there any properties that support this feature?

In other words, is there a property that keeps the `checked check` in its state even if it is still

selected?

tried in java code but failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089150/set-com-google-android-material-chip-chip-selected-color ?

Comment: hm.. thank you. but at your link, `style`  doesn't work..`@color` doesn't work..

Comment: Right click on the `Res` directory of your project while running Android Studio, then click on `New -> New resource file` and select `resourse type` as color then create your `bg_chip_state_list` color file.

Comment: OMG, i solved it! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, is there a property that keeps the checked check in its state even if it is still
>
> selected?

Use Chip Choice then add the chips inside ChipGroup.

Add this line to your ChipGroup

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
app:singleSelection="true"
app:selectionRequired="true"
app:checkedChip="@id/..."
..>
```

Then in your Chip

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
android:id="@+id/chip1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checkable="true"
android:checked="true"
app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"
app:chipText="Test1" />

<android.support.design.chip.Chip
android:id="@+id/chip2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checkable="true"
app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"
app:chipText="Test2" />
```

The key is the ChipGroup that has required selection