# How to change backround color of android chips programmatically on selected state?

Tags: android, kotlin, chips

i have a project that user chose a chip and backround color changes with that, in this context,  i have created a backround xml file that contains selected states = true and false. Also when set backround color with this file it gets backround color hereby does not set color of selected state under this circumtances you can find sample code in below;

fragment that i set backround programmatically:

```
private fun createChip(label: String, time: String, id: Int): Chip {
    val chip = Chip(context, null, R.style.CustomChipStyle)

    chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.chip_background_color))

    chip.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    chip.text = label
    chip.isCheckable = true
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.setOnClickListener {
        binding.lytSelectTime.removeAllViews()

        binding.lytSelectTime


        val scrollView = HorizontalScrollView(context)
        val chipGroup = ChipGroup(context)
        chipGroup.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

chip backroundColor xml file code;

```
<item android:color="@color/corporate_green" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:color="@color/corporate_blue2" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your efforts...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set com.google.android.material.chip.Chip selected color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089150/set-com-google-android-material-chip-chip-selected-color)

Comment: thank you i have applied the same thing but could not get a sollution also i m trying to apply  this programmatically thank you so much for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your checked Id and you can change your background by this snippet Programmatically.

```
chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColorForBackground))
chip.chipStrokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColorForBorder))
chip.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.edWhite)))
chip.chipStrokeWidth = 2.0f
```

Comment: thank you so much also how can i get checked id please

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding the chip dynamic in ChipGroup but your singleSlection
is not working then make sure chip.isCheckable=true then it will work
like`

```
val chip=Chip(this)
           chip.setText(chiparray[i])
           chip.chipBackgroundColor= ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.chip_background_color))
           chip.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.chip_text_color)))
           chip.isCheckable=true//make sure clickable is true 

          chip.setChipBackgroundColor(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.chip_background_color));

          chip.setOnClickListener {
              val chip=it as Chip
              chip.isChecked=true
              categoryName=chip.text.toString()
          }
          binding.chipGrop.isSingleSelection=true
          binding.chipGrop.addView(chip)
`
```